# How I can split the text from a txt file in jquery

Tags: jquery, random

I am working on a random quote generator website.

I am storing my quotes in a text file with quotes like this:

```
"Quote1"    
"Quote2"    
...
```

How can I split them in jquery?
Here is what I am using:

```
var array_quotes = new Array();

$.get('quotes.txt', function (data) {
    array_quotes = data.split("/n");
```

Comment: Try to split on newline i.e. `\n`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve text file line-by-line using Jquery $.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535882/retrieve-text-file-line-by-line-using-jquery-get)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve text file line-by-line using Jquery $.get()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6535882/retrieve-text-file-line-by-line-using-jquery-get)

Answer (score 0):

Using

> split()

function of JavaScript , you can achieve it.

If you want to split using new line then :

```
val().split("\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var file = "quotes.txt";
var array_quotes = [];
function getFile(){
    $.get(file,function(txt){
        var lines = txt.responseText.split("\n");
        for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {
            array_quotes.push(lines[i]);
        }
    }); 
}
```